# Deleting entity from core data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

After making a rough version of my app, I am now looking to make the finalised version which is better and has many improvements. This involves changing the attributes in the entity holding the timers.

Having put the app on TestFlight already, some of the downloads will have data stored already. I am going to delete the current entity and make a new one. Will this cause any problems if data is already stored for the attributes within the entity that is going to be deleted?

IMPORTANT: I do not want to keep any of the data in the entity to delete and I want to delete it all, so when users update all their data will be gone (this is fine as I distributed it only to people I know e.g. family/friends), who have given some feedback.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You asked the same question twice. Please don’t do that.

Comment: It is because I wanted to change the context and explain it in a better way.

Comment: @D-AUK FYI, better in that case to edit your existing question rather than create a new one.  Or if you really want to start afresh, delete the original.

Comment: Ok - do you have an answer please?

Comment: Just writing something now....

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is very pedantic.  Once a store has been created based on a data model, you cannot use it with a different model unless you do some kind of migration.  Different in this case means almost any change to the model.  Certainly changing the attributes for an entity, or adding a new entity, will be sufficient for CoreData to throw an exception if you try to open the existing store with the new model.

If you want to preserve the data in the existing store, you would have to do a migration, but since you do not want to preserve that data, it will be easier to delete the store when the new version of your app is first run, and let CoreData create a new store using the new model.

Comment: I am using the same data model. When you say delete the store when the first version is run, does that require code, or just select backspace on the entity description?

Comment: That requires code - probably in the AppDelegate, when `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is triggered, or when the CD stack is created.

Comment: Just to delete an entity description?

Comment: Deleting the entity in the data model you can do just by hitting backspace when the entity is selected in the data model editor.  But that will register as a change to the model.  Your model will then be incompatible with the existing data store, and that's why you need either to delete the existing store, or to use a different one.

Comment: That's funny. I deleted a core data entity description and everything has been working ever since. Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps you are using NSPersistentContainer to create your CoreData stack - that invokes a lightweight migration automatically if necessary.